# Why I get float when I changed it to integer

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing a function to change from float to integer. Right now, for example, if the value is 1.34, the code returns 1.0 instead of 1. How to solve this problem?

```
dataframe.iloc[:,i] = dataframe.iloc[:,i].apply(lambda x: int(x) if str(x) != 'nan' else x)
```

Comment: Your datafame's dtype is probably a float type. You cannot store int type in a float dataframe.

Comment: If I never add the if else clause, I can get it in int format

Comment: It probably casts to the most flexible type. the else leaves some floats (with `nan`) value in the dataframe along with the ints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `NaN` is a `float`:

```
>>> type(np.nan)
<class 'float'>
>>>
```

Even 1 out of a million values is a float, than the whole thing is a float.

So you could use:

```
df.iloc[:, i] = df.iloc[:, i].astype('Int64')
```

You can do `Int64`, `Int32` or `Int16`.